# Cannot get stream in socket java

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, objectinputstream

Source:

```
while (true) {
  System.out.println("Waiting");
  ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  System.out.println("Rcvd Stream");
  client listener.onDataReceived(ois.readObject());
}
```

Output

```
Waiting
```

Cannot get input stream.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my src
https://github.com/Saakethjayarama/JavaSocket/tree/main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads some data and waits until the data is read. Make sure it is sent (and flushed) before *on the other side*:

```java
try(ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(socker.getOutputStream())){
    oos.flush();//make sure the data is actually sent
}
```

Make sure to flush *after* creating the `ObjectOutputStream` and *before* creating the `ObjectInputStream` - ideally on both sides. You should flush between writing and reading something whenever it needs to be written before being read.

Aside from that, you might want to create the `ObjectInputStream` once (before the loop) and read data multiple times using the same `ObjectInputStream`:

```java
System.out.println("Waiting");
try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()){
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Rcvd Stream");
        clientListener.onDataReceived(ois.readObject());
    }
}
```

This also uses a try-with-resources block in order to make sure the stream (and socket) is properly closed.

Also note that

> **Deserialization of untrusted data is inherently dangerous and should be avoided. Untrusted data should be carefully validated according to the "Serialization and Deserialization" section of the [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase19&id=secure_coding_guidelines_javase). [Serialization Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase19&id=serialization_filter_guide) describes best practices for defensive use of serial filters.**

Deserializing (untrusted) data from the network leads to denial of service (typically easy to exploit) up to remote code execution attacks (more difficult to exploit) as it may create/deserialize (almost) arbitrary object graphs.

(from the [Javadoc of `ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html))

Comment: Tried flushing the stream after writing it. Still didn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/Saakethjayarama/JavaSocket/tree/main here's the code for reference

Comment: Make sure to flush **after** creating the `ObjectOutputStream` and **before** creating the `ObjectOutputStream` - ideally on both sides. Basically, you should flush between writing and reading something whenever it needs to be written before being read. Also, where exactly does it get stuck (both the server and the client)?

Comment: And I would recommend you not to use `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` when transmitting `byte[]`s. Instead, you might want to first write the length of the array and then the array in raw form (`OutputStream#write`).

Comment: Tried flushing on both side and it worked. Thank you soo much.